# getMessageById returns null

Tags: java, bots, discord-jda

This code supposed to add reactions on a specific message using ID it got from slash-command. It gets the channel's and message's IDs perfectly but when it goes to searching for the message to add reactions the message is `null`. I believe the problem is in `messageReactionAdd()` method. The method gets all it needs to add reactions.

```
package org.rathercruel.bot.commands.roles;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Guild;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel.concrete.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.emoji.Emoji;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.interaction.command.SlashCommandInteractionEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SetRoleMessage extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onSlashCommandInteraction(SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
        if (event.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("set-message-reactions")) {
            String channelID = event.getChannel().getId();
            String messageID = event.getOption("message-id").getAsString();

            Guild guild = event.getGuild();

            List<Emoji> newEmojiList = new ArrayList<>();

            newEmojiList.add(Emoji.fromUnicode("U+1F5FD")); // Statue of Liberty [0]
            newEmojiList.add(Emoji.fromUnicode("U+26A1")); // Voltage
            newEmojiList.add(Emoji.fromUnicode("U+1F6B0")); // Glass of water
            newEmojiList.add(Emoji.fromUnicode("U+1F4BB")); // computer
            newEmojiList.add(Emoji.fromUnicode("U+1F413")); // Rooster
            newEmojiList.add(Emoji.fromUnicode("U+1F414")); // Chicken
            newEmojiList.add(Emoji.fromUnicode("U+1F480")); // Skull [6]

            // call the problem method
            messageReactionAdd(event, channelID, messageID, newEmojiList);
        }
    }

    private void messageReactionAdd(SlashCommandInteractionEvent event, String channelID, String messageID, List<Emoji> emojiList) {
        Guild guild = event.getGuild();
        TextChannel channel = guild.getTextChannelById(channelID);
        Message message = channel.getHistory().getMessageById(messageID);

        if (message != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < emojiList.size(); i++) {
                message.addReaction(emojiList.get(i)).queue();
            }
        // Returns this code:
        } else {
            event.reply("Unknown message.").setEphemeral(true).queue();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use different variables such as `String` and `long` but result is the same in both cases. Also I've tried to find the message inside the `onSlashCommandInteraction()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will always return null, for every message id:

```java
channel.getHistory().getMessageById(messageID)
```

As per the documentation:

> From [getHistory](https://docs.jda.wiki/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/channel/middleman/MessageChannel.html#getHistory())
>
> Creates a new MessageHistory object for each call of this method

> From [MessageHistory](https://docs.jda.wiki/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageHistory.html#getMessageById(long))
>
> If a Message with the provided id has not already been retrieved (thus, doesn't exist in this MessageHistory object), then this method returns null.

Since you haven't called any of the retrieve methods, such as `retrievePast`, the retrieved message cache is empty.

You don't want to retrieve the message anyway, since you can add reactions without the message object.

```java
channel.addReactionById(messageId, emoji).queue();
```

See [addReactionById](https://docs.jda.wiki/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/channel/middleman/MessageChannel.html#addReactionById(long,net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.emoji.Emoji)).

If you *do* want to retrieve a message, use [retrieveMessageById](https://docs.jda.wiki/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/channel/middleman/MessageChannel.html#retrieveMessageById(long)) instead.